# lua script error checking

Tags: lua

Is it possible to check if a lua script contains errors without executing it? I have fallowing code:

```
    if(luaL_loadbuffer(L, data, size, name))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", lua_tostring (L, -1));
        lua_pop (L, 1);
    }

    if(lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s", lua_tostring (L, -1));
        lua_pop (L, 1);
    }
```

But if the script contains errors it passes first if and it is executed. I want to know if it contains errors when I load it, not when I execute it. Is this possible?

Comment: We can't down-vote a comment, but if you google for "Lua lint" you might change your mind about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This was originally meant as a reply to the first comment to Krtek's question, but I ran out of space there and to be honest it works as an answer just fine.)

Functions are essentially values, and thus a named function is actually a variable of that name. Variables, by their very definition, can change as a script is executed. Hell, someone might accidentally redefine one of those functions. Is that bad? To sum my thoughts up: depending on the script, parameters passed and/or actual implementations of those pre-defined functions you speak of (one might unset itself or others, for example), it is not possible to guarantee things work unless you are willing to narrow down some of your demands. Lua is too dynamic for what you are looking for. :)

If you want a **flawless** test: create a dummy environment with all bells and whistles in place, and see if it crashes anywhere along the way (loading, executing, etc). This is basically a sort of unit test, and as such would be pretty heavy.

If you want a **basic check to see if a script has a valid syntax**: Krtek gave an answer for that already. I am quite sure (but not 100%) that the lua equivalent is to `loadfile` or `loadstring`, and the respective C equivalent is to try and `lua_load()` the code, each of which convert readable script to bytecode which you would already need to do before you could actually execute the code in your normal all-is-well usecase. (And if that contained function definitions, those would need to be executed later on for the code inside those to execute.)

However, these are the extent of your options with regards to pre-empting errors before they actually happen. Lua is a very dynamic language, and what is a great strength also makes for a weakness when you want to prove correctness. There are simply too many variables involved for a perfect solution.

Comment: I wanted to check this because I will have many scrips, some of them executed only in special conditions that will be hard to test. I will make unit tests for all the scrips with stub functions for my C++ functions to be sure they exist, but also to avoid executing them. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Glad I could help. :) You can most likely create a sort of `GenerateStub(param1type, param2type, ...)` function that creates and returns a function that throws errors if one or more of the parameters are not of an proper type. That way you could check for more than a functions existence: you may check if the supplied parameters are of correct types with a risk of false errors. Example: if a real function supposedly fills a table with numbers, when another passes a value from it to a stub function, your test run would pass nil (and not a number!) which then causes the stub to falsely error out.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [LUA Compiler](http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/luac.html). It will only compile your file to bytecode without executing it.

Your program will also have the advantage the run faster if it is compiled.

You can even use the `-p` option to only perform a syntax checking, according to the linked man page :

> -p load files but do not generate any output file. Used mainly for syntax checking or testing precompiled chunks: corrupted files will probably generate errors when loaded. For a thourough integrity test, use -t.

Comment: I can't use it because I have registered functions from my app and the compiler can't know anything about these functions. I'm not interested to have only syntax checking, I want also to know if somebody calls functions that are not registered(maybe some spelling problems).

Comment: Ow. Lua 4.0? Current version is 5.1

Comment: @Alexender so just because I linked to an old manual entry I get a downvote ? Btw, this is the first result for "lua compiler" on Google, sorry I didn't check the address bar ;)

Answer (score 5):

In general it is not possible, as Lua is a dynamic language, and most of errors happen in runtime.

If you want to check for syntax errors, use `luac -p` option. I use it as a part of my pre-commit hook, for example.

Other common errors are triggering by misusing the global variables. You may analyze output of `luac -l` to catch these cases. See here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/DetectingUndefinedVariables.

If you want something more advanced, there are several more-or-less functional static analysis tools for Lua code. Start with [LuaInspect](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaInspect).

In any case, you are advised to write unit tests instead of just relying on static code checks. Less pain, more gain.