# Checking validity of Lua code?

Tags: c#, lua

I have some Lua code in C# as a string and I'd like to check if it's valid (any syntax errors, that sort of thing).

How can I go about doing that in a quick and efficient manner?

edit: the other suggested duplicate question does not simply check for valid syntax but valid code, luaL_loadstirng fails when a line of valid lua code is given to it if that valid line requires other variables declared before it.

Comment: some googling returns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145094/c-sharp-lua-parser-analyser

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249709/lua-script-error-checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile it. Call `Lua.LoadString`. That will give you compile-time errors (syntax errors). To find runtime errors, you're just going to need to run it.

Comment: This works but what I ended up needing to do is enclose the lua function string in a "function test()" [lua to validate] + "end"